# Django NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add_continue' with arguments '('',)'

Tags: python, django

Anyone know what could be causing this error I'm getting? Most of the other code, which works the exact same way, works perfectly. However, this button doesn't work whenever I click it for some reason. The error only happens once the button to add a movie to a watchlist is clicked. I've checked out some of the other suggestions on here and none of them seem directly correlated to this issue. Any suggestions?

Here is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /watchlist/
Reverse for 'add_continue' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['resumeMovie/add/(?P<film_id>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/$']
```

Watchlist.html:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load static %} {% block metadescription %} This is
the watchlist page. Proceed to review your items. {% endblock %} {% block title
%} Watchlist - MovieBuff {% endblock %} {% block content %} {% if not
watchlist_items %}
<div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <br />
    <h1 class="text-center my_title">Your watchlist is empty</h1>
    <br />
    <p class="text-center">
      Please click <a href="{% url 'movies:allFilmGenre' %}">here</a> to
      continue browsing our collection.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <br />
    <h1 class="text-center my_title">Your Watchlist</h1>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mx-auto">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
    <table class="table my_custom_table">
      <thead class="my_custom_thead">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5">Your Films to watch</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for watchlist_item in watchlist_items %}
        <tr class="my_custom_thead">
          <td>
            <a href="{{watchlist_item.film.get_absolute_url}}"
              ><img
                src="{{watchlist_item.film.image.url}}"
                alt=""
                class="float-left rounded custom_image"
            /></a>
          </td>
          <td class="text-left">
            {{watchlist_item.film.name}}
            <br />
            Film Price: €{{watchlist_item.film.price}}
            <br />
          </td>

          {% if watchlist_item.quantity < watchlist_item.film.stock %}
          <td>
            <a
              href="{% url 'watchlist:watchlist_remove' watchlist_item.film.id %}"
              class="btn btn-secondary btn-block my_custom_button"
              >Already Watched</a
            >
            <a
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              href="{% url 'resumeMovie:add_continue' continue_item.film.id %}"
              >Watch Movie</a
            >
          </td>
          <td></td>

          {% else %}
          <td>
            <a
              href="{% url 'watchlist:full_remove' watchlist_item.film.id %}"
              class="btn btn-secondary btn-block my_custom_button"
              >Already Watched</a
            >
            <a
              href="{% url 'resumeMovie:full_remove' continue_item.film.id %}"
              class="btn btn-success btn-block"
              >Finish Watching</a
            >
          </td>
          <td></td>
          {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
{% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```py
def _watchlist_id(request):
    watchlist = request.session.session_key
    if not watchlist:
        watchlist = request.session.create()
    return watchlist


def add_watchlist(request, film_id):
    film = Film.objects.get(id=film_id)
    try:
        watchlist = Watchlist.objects.get(watchlist_id=_watchlist_id(request))
    except Watchlist.DoesNotExist:
        watchlist = Watchlist.objects.create(
                watchlist_id=_watchlist_id(request)
            )
        watchlist.save()
    try:
        watchlist_item = WatchlistItem.objects.get(film=film, watchlist=watchlist)
        if watchlist_item.quantity < watchlist_item.film.stock:
            watchlist_item.quantity += 1
        watchlist_item.save()
    except WatchlistItem.DoesNotExist:
        watchlist_item = WatchlistItem.objects.create(
                        film = film,
                        quantity = 1,
                        watchlist = watchlist
        )
        watchlist_item.save()
    return redirect('watchlist:watchlist_detail')

def watchlist_detail(request, total = 0, counter=0, watchlist_items=None):
    try:
        watchlist = Watchlist.objects.get(watchlist_id=_watchlist_id(request))
        watchlist_items = WatchlistItem.objects.filter(watchlist=watchlist, active=True)
        for watchlist_item in watchlist_items:
            total += (watchlist_item.film.price * watchlist_item.quantity)
            counter += watchlist_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    return render(request, 'watchlist.html', {'watchlist_items':watchlist_items, 'counter':counter})

def watchlist_remove(request, film_id):
    watchlist = Watchlist.objects.get(watchlist_id=_watchlist_id(request))
    film = get_object_or_404(Film, id=film_id)
    watchlist_item = WatchlistItem.objects.get(film=film, watchlist=watchlist)
    if watchlist_item.quantity > 1:
        watchlist_item.quantity -= 1
        watchlist_item.save()
    else:
        watchlist_item.delete()
    return redirect('watchlist:watchlist_detail')


def full_remove(request, film_id):
    watchlist = Watchlist.objects.get(watchlist_id=_watchlist_id(request))
    film = get_object_or_404(Film, id=film_id)
    watchlist_item = WatchlistItem.objects.get(film=film, watchlist=watchlist)
    watchlist_item.delete()
    return redirect('watchlist:watchlist_detail')

def _continue_id(request):
    resume = request.session.session_key
    if not resume:
        resume = request.session.create()
    return resume


def add_continue(request, film_id):
    film = Film.objects.get(id=film_id)
    try:
        resume = Resume.objects.get(continue_id=_continue_id(request))
    except Resume.DoesNotExist:
        resume = Resume.objects.create(
                continue_id=_continue_id(request)
            )
        resume.save()
    try:
        continue_item = ResumeItem.objects.get(film=film, resume=resume)
        if continue_item.quantity < continue_item.film.stock:
            continue_item.quantity += 1
        continue_item.save()
    except ResumeItem.DoesNotExist:
        continue_item = ResumeItem.objects.create(
                        film = film,
                        quantity = 1,
                        resume = resume
        )
        continue_item.save()
    return redirect('resumeMovie:continue_detail')

def continue_remove(request, film_id):
    resume = Resume.objects.get(continue_id=_continue_id(request))
    film = get_object_or_404(Film, id=film_id)
    continue_item = ResumeItem.objects.get(film=film, resume=resume)
    if continue_item.quantity > 1:
        continue_item.quantity -= 1
        continue_item.save()
    else:
        continue_item.delete()
    return redirect('resume:continue_detail')
```

Comment: The issue appears to be `continue_item`.  Your view `watchlist_detail` is not passing anything named `continue_item` to the template context, nor is it the iterator variable of a loop in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Is continue_item available in the template context, it might be missing. Try to print it.